# Rails routes.rb not working as desired with named routes

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have this code to link to a new persona:

```
<%= link_to "New Persona", genesis_path, class: "new-persona-button" %>
```

My routes.rb file:

```
Bazleyapp::Application.routes.draw do

  resources :users,    only: [:index, :create]
  resources :personas, only: [:index, :create]

  root                       'static_pages#home'

  get     'signup',                 to:  'users#new'
  get     '/:callsign',             to:  'users#show',     as: :user
  get     '/:callsign/settings',    to:  'users#edit',     as: :edit_user
  patch   '/:callsign',             to:  'users#update',   as: :update_user
  delete  '/:callsign/terminated',  to:  'users#destroy',  as: :destroy_user

  get     'genesis',                to:  'personas#new'
  get     '/:callsign',             to:  'personas#show',     as: :persona
  get     '/:callsign/settings',    to:  'personas#edit',     as: :edit_persona
  patch   '/:callsign',             to:  'personas#update',   as: :update_persona
  delete  '/:callsign/terminated',  to:  'personas#destroy',  as: :destroy_persona

end
```

Clicking on the new persona button produces this error:

```
Started GET "/genesis" for ::1 at 2014-12-03 00:25:38 +0000
Processing by UsersController#show as HTML
Parameters: {"callsign"=>"genesis"}
User Load (0.4ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."callsign" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["callsign", "bazzer"]]
User Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."callsign" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["callsign", "genesis"]]
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 21ms

NoMethodError (undefined method `activated' for nil:NilClass):
app/controllers/users_controller.rb:17:in `show'
```

Which means it's hitting the user_path (users#show) when it should be hitting the genesis_path. But I've told it to hit the genesis path with `<%= link_to "New Persona", genesis_path, class: "new-persona-button" %>`. Am baffled. Where is the error?

Answer (score 1):

Put

```
get 'genesis', to: 'personas#new'
```

before

```
get '/:callsign', to: 'users#show', as: :user
```

You have to know that the routes file is read from top to bottom.

Comment: But why doesn't using `genesis_path` tell it to go straight to the personas/new action?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think what you have here is going to work as you are overwriting several routes. You may want to consider putting these in separate namespaces so they are unique.

Example:

```
Bazleyapp::Application.routes.draw do

  resources :users,    only: [:index, :create]
  resources :personas, only: [:index, :create]

  root                       'static_pages#home'

  namespace :users do
    get     'signup',                 to:  'users#new'
    get     '/:callsign',             to:  'users#show',     as: :user
    get     '/:callsign/settings',    to:  'users#edit',     as: :edit_user
    patch   '/:callsign',             to:  'users#update',   as: :update_user
    delete  '/:callsign/terminated',  to:  'users#destroy',  as: :destroy_user
  end

  namespace :personas do
    get     'genesis',                to:  'personas#new'
    get     '/:callsign',             to:  'personas#show',     as: :persona
    get     '/:callsign/settings',    to:  'personas#edit',     as: :edit_persona
    patch   '/:callsign',             to:  'personas#update',   as: :update_persona
    delete  '/:callsign/terminated',  to:  'personas#destroy',  as: :destroy_persona
  end
end
```

That way you separate paths for these routes.

You can also add a block to the resource and not have to split it up. Example:

```
resources :users,    only: [:index, :create] do
  get     'signup',                 to:  'users#new'
  get     '/:callsign',             to:  'users#show',     as: :user
  get     '/:callsign/settings',    to:  'users#edit',     as: :edit_user
  patch   '/:callsign',             to:  'users#update',   as: :update_user
  delete  '/:callsign/terminated',  to:  'users#destroy',  as: :destroy_user
end
```

Comment: Thank you. But surely my original code should work, and this shouldn't be necessary? I have used named routes. Surely by telling rails to use genesis_path it should skip the user_path?

Comment: I thought the whole idea of named routes was so you could give them individual names and make sure one route wasn't confused with another?!

Comment: `get 'genesis'` creates the named route `genesis_path` does it not?

Comment: It still doesn't work when I add `as: :genesis_path`:

`get 'genesis', to: 'personas#new', as: :genesis_path`

Comment: The way you have it written rails isn't going to be able to differentiate between `get '/:callsign', to: 'users#show', as: :user` and `get '/:callsign', to:  'users#show', as: :user` when a user tries to access those pages. It will create the path methods for them (e.g. user_path and persona_path) but they wont be unique.